# mac shell script trouble with mkvirtualenv

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am creating a shell script to create a new python virtual environment, activate it, install django and other apps. I am running into an issue with running workon command. Any ideas?

```
   1 #!/bin/bash
   2 export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Development/Python/Django/.virtualenvs
   3 export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Development/Python/Django/dev
   4 source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
   5 
   6 ENV_NAME="$1"
   7 
   8 #Create the virtual environment
   9 mkvirtualenv $ENV_NAME --no-site-packages
  10 
  11 #workon the newly created environment
  12 workon $ENV_NAME
  13 
  14 #install django
  15 #pip install django
  16 
  17 #install apps
  18 #pip install south
  19 #pip install fabric
  20 #pip install django-debug-toolbar
  21 #pip install django-extensions
  22 #pip install compressor
  23 
  24 exit
  25
```

After the script exits the environment is not activated.

I tried adding line 2 and 3 but that did not help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a script normally, it executes in a subshell. What this script does is sets that subshell's environment up properly... and then exits, leaving *your* shell's environment untouched. `export` is not relevant here, that passes those parts of the environment down to subprocesses, not up to parent processes.

In order for this to work, you must `source` the script, (or use the `.` command, which is a synonym for source). That makes the current shell run the script, rather than delegating it to a subshell.

I tend to recommend removing or changing the shebang (`#!`) line for scripts that need to be run with `source` -- having a normal shebang indicates it's a normal script and can be run normally, which is completely misleading. My personal preference is to change it to:

```
#!/bin/echo please run this with the source command
```

...so that if anyone ever tries to run it like a normal script, it'll tell them how to run it correctly.

Or you could just remove execute permission and call it done.